# Submit a handsontable to a spring mvc3 controller - Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' not supported

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc, handsontable

im new to spring mvc3 and am looking at a jquery handsontable example.

here is my part of my jsp page that includes the form

```
  <form:form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/app/${application.id}/user/bulkImport" method="POST">   
        <div id="dataTable"></div>
        <script>
            var data = [
                ["156428", "admin,SCC,Superuser"],
                ["839302", "SCC"]
            ];
            $("#dataTable").handsontable({
                data: data,
                startRows: 3,
                startCols: 2
            });
</script>   
   <script>
   function submitEntries(){
        alert("in");
            var tableData = $("#dataTable").handsontable("getData");
            var formDataJson = JSON.stringify({"data":tableData});
             jQuery.ajax({
                url: 'bulkImport',
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                data: formDataJson,
                'success': function (e) {
                    var resultString = 'saved';
                    $('#serverResults').html(resultString);
                }
            });
   }
    </script>
```

controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/bulkImport", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String importUsers(@RequestBody BulkUserImportEntries entries)
            throws Exception {

        Iterator itr = entries.getData().iterator();
        while(itr.hasNext()) {
            Object obj = (Object)itr.next();
        }

        return "redirect:/app/{appId}/user/{id}";
    }
```

BulkUserImportEntries class:

```
public class BulkUserImportEntries implements Serializable{ 
      private List<Object[]> data;

      protected BulkUserImportEntries() {}
      protected BulkUserImportEntries(List<Object[]> data) {
            this.data = data;
      }

      public List<Object[]> getData() {
            return data;
      }
}
```

im getting this error when submitting the form.

Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' not supported

I would like to recieve the array of values from my jsp to be able to iterate it on the controller. i see this is possible on the example but this is using a modelAttribute . Again im pretty new and have been stuck here for a week now :(

Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when we use **application/x-www-form-urlencoded**, Spring doesn't understand it as a RequestBody. So, if we want to use this
we must remove the **@RequestBody** annotation.

Then try the following:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/bulkImport", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
public String importUsers(BulkUserImportEntries entries) throws Exception {

    Iterator itr = entries.getData().iterator();
    while(itr.hasNext()) {
        Object obj = (Object)itr.next();
    }

    return "redirect:/app/{appId}/user/{id}";
}
```

Note that removed the annotation **@RequestBody** and add **consumes** = *MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE*

*answer*: [Http Post request with content type application/x-www-form-urlencoded not working in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34782025/http-post-request-with-content-type-application-x-www-form-urlencoded-not-workin/38252762#38252762)

Comment: Solved my problem. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

Try

`contentType: "application/json",`

instead of

```
headers: {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
},
```

in your jsp file.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i did try that but i still get the same error.