# Http Post request with content type application/x-www-form-urlencoded not working in Spring

Tags: java, jquery, spring, rest, spring-mvc

Am new to spring currently am trying to do *HTTP POST request application/x-www-form-url encoded* but when i keep this in my headers then spring not recognizing it and saying `415 Unsupported Media Type`
for `x-www-form-urlencoded`

> org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content
>   type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' not supported

Can any one know how to solve it? please comment me.

An example of my controller is:

```
@RequestMapping(
    value = "/patientdetails",
    method = RequestMethod.POST,
    headers="Accept=application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
public @ResponseBody List<PatientProfileDto> getPatientDetails(
        @RequestBody PatientProfileDto name
) { 
    List<PatientProfileDto> list = new ArrayList<PatientProfileDto>();
    list = service.getPatient(name);
    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 58):

The problem is that when we use **application/x-www-form-urlencoded**, Spring doesn't understand it as a RequestBody. So, if we want to use this
we must remove the **@RequestBody** annotation.

Then try the following:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/patientdetails", method = RequestMethod.POST,consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody List<PatientProfileDto> getPatientDetails(
        PatientProfileDto name) {


    List<PatientProfileDto> list = new ArrayList<PatientProfileDto>();
    list = service.getPatient(name);
    return list;
}
```

Note that removed the annotation **@RequestBody**

Comment: this is correct. but for a PATCH method I need the @RequestBody or my objects are empty (all fields are null)

Comment: found a solution, without using @RequestBody add a filter like here:
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-form-urlencoded-data

Answer (score 16):

you should replace **@RequestBody** with **@RequestParam**, and do not accept parameters with a java entity.

Then you controller is probably like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/patientdetails", method = RequestMethod.POST, 
consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE})
public @ResponseBody List<PatientProfileDto> getPatientDetails(
    @RequestParam Map<String, String> name) {
   List<PatientProfileDto> list = new ArrayList<PatientProfileDto>();
   ...
   PatientProfileDto patientProfileDto = mapToPatientProfileDto(mame);
   ...
   list = service.getPatient(patientProfileDto);
   return list;
}
```

Answer (score 14):

The solution can be found here https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/22734

you can create two separate post request mappings. For example.

```
@PostMapping(path = "/test", consumes = "application/json")
public String test(@RequestBody User user) {
  return user.toString();
}

@PostMapping(path = "/test", consumes = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
public String test(User user) {
  return user.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove @ResponseBody annotation from your use parameters in method.  Like this;

```
   @Autowired
    ProjectService projectService;

    @RequestMapping(path = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<Project> createNewProject(Project newProject){
        Project project = projectService.save(newProject);

        return new ResponseEntity<Project>(project,HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest thing to do is to set the content type of your ajax request to `"application/json; charset=utf-8"` and then let your API method consume JSON. Like this:

```
var basicInfo = JSON.stringify({
    firstName: playerProfile.firstName(),
    lastName: playerProfile.lastName(),
    gender: playerProfile.gender(),
    address: playerProfile.address(),
    country: playerProfile.country(),
    bio: playerProfile.bio()
});

$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:8080/social/profile/update",
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: basicInfo,
    success: function(data) {
        // ...
    }
});


@RequestMapping(
    value = "/profile/update",
    method = RequestMethod.POST,
    produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
    consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<ResponseModel> UpdateUserProfile(
    @RequestBody User usersNewDetails,
    HttpServletRequest request,
    HttpServletResponse response
) {
    // ...
}
```

I guess the problem is that Spring Boot has issues submitting form data which is not JSON via ajax request.

Note: the default content type for ajax is `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`.

Answer (score 0):

replace contentType : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", by dataType : "text" as wildfly 11 doesn't support mentioned contenttype..

Answer (score -1):

You have to tell Spring what input content-type is supported by your service. You can do this with the "consumes" Annotation Element that corresponds to your request's "Content-Type" header.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = {"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"})
```

It would be helpful if you posted your code.

Comment: Status 415 Unsupported Media Type
message displaying

Comment: Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' not supported

Comment: Did you add the request mapping annotation with the "consumes" parameter?

Comment: @RequestMapping(value = "/patientdetails", method = RequestMethod.POST,consumes = {"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"})

 org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' not supported

Comment: shall i add anything in config xml. ?

Comment: Adding `consumes` does the same as adding the header like you did. @Douglas answer is partial as part of your problem relates to using `@RequestBody`. However when you try to bind your request to a DTO Spring also returns 415. Change the parameter type to `MultiValueMap` and it will work.