# Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' not supported" for post method

Tags: spring, http

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {

    @PostMapping(value = "/",
            consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE,
            produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
    public ResponseEntity<InternalUser> saveInternalUser(@RequestBody InternalUserDTO dto){

       InternalUser user =  internalUserService.saveInternalUser(dto);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(user, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
```

this is my class. WHen i use postman with valid json to that url
 http://localhost:8090/user

i get error of

```
Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' not supported]
```

i tried this
https://stackoverflow.com/a/38252762/11369236

I dont want to use requestparam like here

https://stackoverflow.com/a/43065261/11369236

Some answers suggest to use

```
          consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON,
```

but spring gives errors:

```
attribute must be constant
```

What can i do?

Answer (score 4):

You have to add `Content-type: application/json;charset=utf-8` header to your request.

By default (if `Content-type` header is absent) content type of POST request body is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. 
In `@RequestMapping` by `consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE` mentioned that json in `UTF-8` encoding expected in request body. Thats why spring throws an exception.

Answer (score 2):

Use body > **raw** to send your JSON data for the API request

```json
{
    "name": "John Doe"
    "email": "xyz@abc.com"
}
```

[POSTMAN-POST-REQUEST](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FR5Az.png)

Comment: May you please send your POSTMAN screenshots of Header and BODY tabs? So that i can see and analyse more on it