# Why controller code not getting executed in spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jsp

I am trying to make a simple `Spring Boot application` in `STS 3` where users can signup and create their account. I am using `PostgreSQL` database and `JPA` with hibernate. Following is the code.

The **entity class**:

```
package tv.app.user;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class UserAccount {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long uid;

    private String username;
    private String email;
    private String password;

    public long getUid() {
        return uid;
    }

    public void setUid(long uid) {
        this.uid = uid;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

The **controller**:

```
package tv.app.user;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class UserAccountController {

    @Autowired
    UserAccountService userAccountService;

    @RequestMapping(value="/register", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public void registerAccount(@RequestBody UserAccount user) {
        System.out.println("------2------");
        System.out.println(user.getfName());
        userAccountService.register(user);
    }
}
```

The **repository**:

```
package tv.app.user;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface UserAccountRepository extends CrudRepository<UserAccount, Long> {

}
```

The **buisness service class**:

```
package tv.app.user;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class UserAccountService {

    @Autowired
    private UserAccountRepository userRepository;

    public void register(UserAccount user) {
        userRepository.save(user);
    }
}
```

**Jsp form**:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/register" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" required /><br>
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email ID" required /><br>
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required /><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Signup" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The **application.properties** file:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create

spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.datasource.platform=postgres
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/myApp
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=postgres
```

It seems that after clicking submit, the control never enters the controller, as the ---2--- is never outputted to the console even though the action in the form is same as the request mapping.

The error that is showing is:

> There was an unexpected error (type=Unsupported Media Type, status=415).
>   Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' not supported

Comment: Have you tried setting the `consumes` attribute for your request mapping annotation to indicate what media types you accept?

Comment: No, I do not know that. Can you please explain. @Mike

Comment: Try adding `consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE` to your `@RequestMapping` annotation.

Comment: Tried it but did not work. @Mike

Comment: Still 415 response?

Comment: yes, same error

Comment: Try this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38252762/657224

Comment: Thanks Mike, that solved my issue. :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are calling the exact endpoint that is declared in your controller (localhost:port/register). If you aren´t callign correctly an  HTTP 404 error could be outputted...check for that.

If you aren´t getting any HTTP errors, I would change the annotations to this format (and change the call accordingly to /register/user) (as the Spring guides [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/)):

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/register")
public class UserAccountController {

@Autowired
UserAccountService userAccountService;

@PostMapping("/user")
public void registerAccount(@RequestBody UserAccount user) {
    System.out.println("------2------");
    System.out.println(user.getfName());
    userAccountService.register(user);
}
}
```

Comment: The error that is showing is like: There was an unexpected error (type=Unsupported Media Type, status=415). Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' not supported

Comment: Where are you calling your controller from? Make sure you are making a POST call and try declaring your header value as: application/json