# How to put id in redirect(@PutMapping)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to redirect to `/post/`user's id when user update data. but following code is not working.

```
@PutMapping("/post/edit/{id}")
    public String update(@PathVariable("id") Long id , @RequestBody BoardDto boardDto) {
        boardService.savePost(boardDto);
        return "redirect:/post/" + id;
   }


@PathVariable("id") Long id
@PathVariable Long id
@PathVariable String id
```

`Whiteable` page error pops up too

```
WARN 12524 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' not supported]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Http Post request with content type application/x-www-form-urlencoded not working in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34782025/http-post-request-with-content-type-application-x-www-form-urlencoded-not-workin)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Redirect to an external URL from controller action in Spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17955777/redirect-to-an-external-url-from-controller-action-in-spring-mvc)

Comment: that's it! Thank you