# Why is Spring Boot returning a 403 on POST when permitAll is being used?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Ok I am a little confused, to debug I have reverted to this...

```java
.authorizeHttpRequests((authz) -> authz.anyRequest().permitAll())
```

And I have the following

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("contact")
public class LeadController {
    @Autowired
    private PotentialContactRepo potentialContactRepo;

    @PostMapping(consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
    public void addContact(@RequestBody PotentialContact contact) {
        potentialContactRepo.save(contact);
    }

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<String> getContact() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Hello");
    }
}
```

But when I call the post endpoint with postman I get a 403 but when I call the get I get a 200.

```
POST /contact HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.31.0
Accept: */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
Host: localhost:8080
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 151
 
name=...&contactInfo=...&location=Wherever&description=This%20is%20the%20description%3B!%40%23%24%23%24%40%24%40%23%24%40%23
 
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Set-Cookie: Path=/; HttpOnly
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 0
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Mon, 27 Nov 2023 05:10:11 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=60
Connection: keep-alive
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Show your Spring Security `TRACE` logs. It shoud show the reason. But probably it is the missing CSRF token.

Comment: @dur The answer in my case wasn't telling me the csrf thing because I had accidentally deleted that while I was debugging a 415 issue. See post for full explanation but yeah thank you for that direction.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like Spring Security configuration what might be the cause for the 403 Forbidden response for your POST request. The `authorizeHttpRequests` method you've shared is granting all requests `permitAll()` , so it should not be causing the issue. So i think Spring Security may be expecting a CSRF token for the POST request, and in Postman might not be sending it. Try disabling CSRF for now to see if it resolves the issue. You can do this by modifying your security configuration `.csrf().disable()` .
Add to your `authorizeHttpRequests` chain ::

```
.authorizeHttpRequests((authz) -> authz
    .anyRequest().permitAll()
)
.csrf().disable();
```

Side Note : It is not a good idea Disabling CSRF for production, but it helps you in debugging

Also please check that you have the `@EnableWebSecurity` annotation added to your configuration class. This annotation enables Spring Security's web security support.
e.g.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {}
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: Spring Boot doesn't need any `@Enable*` annotations

Comment: @ElyorbekIbrokhimov It depends ,Now cause the OP question talking about security issue as a solation he might need a  custom security configurations as an extra solation for his issue

Comment: I take that back I must have deleted it one sec to find out the modern way

Comment: I would also make sure to update to `.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)`

Answer (score 0):

In my case the real answer that helped was from @dur I added

```
logging:
  level:
    org.springframework: TRACE
```

and without going down a rabbit hole this lead me to finally see...

```
Content-Type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' is not supported
```

Which lead me to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34782025/http-post-request-with-content-type-application-x-www-form-urlencoded-not-workin)

Moral in my case was don't use `@RequestBody` with form encoded.